# Disconnect option in Windows Shutdown Dialog while in remote desktop session mysteriously disappeared

Tags: windows-8, remote-desktop, connection

For years I have connected to my home machine (running Windows 8.1) and quickly disconnected from it by clicking anywhere on the desktop, pressing Alt+F4, up arrow and enter.  In other words I was invoking the windows shutdown dialog and choosing the Disconnect option that used to be the first option in the list if I was in a remote desktop session.

This abruptly stopped working a couple months ago in that there is no longer a disconnect option in the shut down dialog's combo box of options. So now I find myself signing out of the machine instead of disconnecting from my session.  It's not a big deal, but it's super annoying... especially since I cannot figure out how to get the disconnect option back.  I can still disconnect the session by going to the start menu and clicking the power icon or by just clicking the x on the remote session title bar.  The disconnect option has only disappeared from the Shutdown menu.

I have another machine in the house running the same version of Windows 8.1 and it still has the Disconnect option when I remote to it.  Also, I have verified that it seems that the computer in question doesn't show a disconnect option regardless of the computer I use to connect to it remotely.

So I'm thinking that there must be something I can change on the computer in question to restore the presence of a disconnect option in the Windows Shutdown menu while in a remote desktop session.

In Local Computer Policy I found a policy called *Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Remote Desktop Services\Remote Desktop Session Host\Remote Session Environment\Remove "Disconnect" option from Shut Down dialog*.  This is not configured which I assume is supposed to mean that the disconnect option should be shown in the shutdown dialog.

If anyone has any ideas on what I can do to get the disconnect option back I'd appreciate hearing them.